# AudioObjectAddPropertyListener for kAudioDevicePropertyNominalSampleRate

Tags: c++, macos, core-audio

I am using an input-enabled AUHAL audio unit to receive input from my internal imac microphone. This works (in my callback I wrote samples to a file and it results in a perfect recording).

Now, **because an input AUHAL may not have a different sample rate than the device it connects to**, I would like my audio unit to react to sample rate changes on the device. To test this, I change the sample rate of the mic in the *Audio Midi Setup* (and indeed, the AUHAL crashes).

I have registered a callback using `AudioObjectAddPropertyListener` with `kAudioDevicePropertyNominalSampleRate`, but it is never called. My breakpoints do not break, and `"callback"` is never couted to my console. Could someone point me to what I am doing wrong? Am I using the wrong scope? The wrong selector?

Changing the selector to `kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar` *does* trigger the callback (when changing the volume, of course), so I assume setting the callback itself is working fine.

```
static OSStatus deviceSampleRateChanged(AudioObjectID inObjectID, UInt32 inNumberAddresses, const AudioObjectPropertyAddress* inAddresses, void* __nullable inClientData)
{
    cout << "callback" << endl;
    return noErr;
}

AudioObjectPropertyAddress address;
address.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyNominalSampleRate;
address.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeInput;
address.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;

AudioObjectAddPropertyListener(unit, &address, &deviceSampleRateChanged, this);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combination of `kAudioDevicePropertyNominalSampleRate` and `kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal` will get the callback to work correctly. The documentation of this selector (CoreAudio/AudioHardware.h) doesn't tell me what scope to use, though. If anyone finds a source of proof/reason for this, feel free to edit.

*The situation is also confusing because calling `AudioObjectSetPropertyData()` with `kAudioDevicePropertyNominalSampleRate` and either `kAudioObjectPropertyScopeInput` or `kAudioObjectPropertyScopeOutput` will **also** result in a successful sample rate switch (one could argue this to be erroneous behaviour).*